# Unexpected behavior when pushing a character to vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, c++14, stdvector

I'm trying to insert a character into vector of strings by converting it to a string first but case 1 is not working but case 2 is working. Can somebody explain the behavior. Any workaround to insert char directly into vector?

```
    // vector of strings
    vector lt; std::string gt; out; 
    // EDIT - stack overflow is not letting me post "less than" sign so using lt; and gt; instead

    // a character
    char ch;

    // assign some value to ch and push to vector

    // CASE 1: don't work
    out.push_back("" + ch);

    // CASE 2: works
    string str = "";
    out.push_back(str + ch);
```

PS - I'm using C++14

Comment: The error message should tell you why it does not work.  Did you try searching the error?  There are plenty of results on google.

Comment: Post real code that actually works.  You have syntax errors.

Comment: Maybe you'll be interested in the string literals: [example](https://ideone.com/OjOV6Y)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for responding.. no error message but the vector is empty..

Comment: -4 votes people? really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `""` does not represent a `std::string` instance, rather it is a `const char*` literal therefore when you add `ch` to it you are performing pointer arithmetic and will likely receive a compiler warning along the lines of:

> warning: array subscript is above array bounds

To `push_back` a `char` as a `std::string` to a `std::vector<std::string>` simply do:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
char ch = 'a';
vec.push_back(std::string()+ch); // construct empty std::string, add ch, push_back
```

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles and works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   // vector of strings

   vector<string> out;

   // a character
   char ch;

   // assign some value to ch and push to vector

   // Case 0: works because a const char * can be coerced into a string
   out.push_back("");

   // Case 1: Does not work 
   // you can't add a const char * and a char.
   // Some compilers coerce the char into an int and add that to the pointer
   // producing undefined behavior (access to un-allocated memory)
   // out.push_back("" + ' ');

   // CASE 1a: Works, but I'm 'cheating' by 
   // explicitly constructing a string.
   out.push_back(string("") + ch);

   // Case 1b: Works using a different string constructor
   // This is probably the best approach:
   out.push_back(string(1, ' '));

   // CASE 2: works
      string str = "";
      out.push_back(str + ch);

   std::cout << "out contains " << out.size() << " entries" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
out contains 3 entries
```

Comment: Works expect 2 lines causing UB :) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e682fa6c9de6678

Comment: Good point.  I'll fix that but it makes this not exactly an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with your code.
Here is type trait that will help you check if name is templated type:

```
/***Check if type is simple template***/
template <template<class...> class>
constexpr bool is_template_type()
{ return true; }

template <class>
constexpr bool is_template_type()
{ return false; }
```

With this, you can check if `vector` is valid type for creating a variable. So:

```
static_assert(!is_template_type<vector>(), 
              "vector is not valid type for creating a variable");
```

Causes compilation to fail, because you can't create variable of `class template`. You have to specify `TYPE` that `std::vector` should store. Your question title says:

> vector of strings

So you should create `std::vector<std::string>` variable instead.

---

Another problem with your code is this:
`"" + ch`. 
What do you think it does? `""` type is `char const[1]`, and `ch` type is `char`. `char const[1]` is implicitly convertible to `char const *`, and since you can add integral value to pointer - it compiles. But this isn't what you want!

Here is your `""` in memory:

```
`\0' ? ? ? ? ? ? ...
/\
```

When you add `ch` to your `""`, this is the result:

```
//ch is 5 for example
`\0' ? ? ? ? ? ? ...
             /\
```

So you create `std::string` with some unspecified address. In reality, accessing array out-of-bounds is Undefined Behaviour in C++.

You should use `std::string() + ch` or string literal syntax that user W.F. posted in his comment to your question.

---

Also don't forget to initialize `ch`, because using unspecified value is Undefined Behaviour too.

Comment: I did put vector<string> not sure why stackoverflow is not showing string part.